# C# deserializing using SharpSerializer results in exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharpserializer

I'm serializing a list of `ObservableCollection<MyType>` using this line of code and it works fine:

```
var serializer = new SharpSerializer(true);
serializer.Serialize(myList, myStreamObject);
```

The problem occurs when I try to deserialize my data.

```
var serializer = new SharpSerializer(true);
this.items = (ObservableCollection<MyType>)serializer.Deserialize(
    myStreamObject);
```

When I debug the return type of `serializer.Deserialize(myStreamObject)` is:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[MyNameSpace.MyType]
```

Thereby resulting in typecast error? How do I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong when deserializing?

Thanks

Comment: You should include the exception information with stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're using `SharpSerializer` for Silverlight or for the full .NET
As default `SharpSerializer` serializes data as short type name. It could be the most probable reason of your error. Try to serialize your data as an `AssemblyFullQualifiedName`:

```
var settings = new SharpSerializerBinarySettings();
settings.IncludeAssemblyVersionInTypeName = true;
settings.IncludeCultureInTypeName = true;
settings.IncludePublicKeyTokenInTypeName = true;

var serializer = new SharpSerializer(settings);
```